# Implementation of ADBannerView on storyboard with autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, adbannerview

I have Xcode 6.3.2 and I have a problem with implementation of ADBannerView on storyboard. Xcode shows all the time a warning:

> Frame for "Banner View" will be different at run time.

I added 3 constraints, you can see them below.

All of constraints
[image: All of constraints]
Center horizontally
[image: Center horizontally]
Bottom space to bottom layout guide = 0
[image: Bottom constraint]
Leading space = 0
[image]

How to implement banner correctly?

I can not use "self.canDisplayBannerAds = true" because I also use "bannerViewDidLoadAd" and "didFailToReceiveAdWithError" to resize content and also "bannerViewActionShouldBegin" and "bannerViewActionDidFinish" to pause and start again application activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

To add iAd banner using Auto Layout and Size Classes in portrait and landscape but without using `canDisplayBannerAds` first declare banner `var bannerView: ADBannerView!`.

Use this to set delegate and add banner to view:

```
func loadAds() {
    bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)
    bannerView.hidden = true
    bannerView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
}
```

Use following code to let banner rotate with screen and resize screen content `contentView` when iAd loads (`bottomConstraint` is a constraint from `contentView` to bottom):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.layoutAnimated(UIView.areAnimationsEnabled())
}

func layoutAnimated(animated: Bool) {
    var contentFrame = self.view.bounds

    var sizeForBanner = bannerView.sizeThatFits(contentFrame.size)

    var bannerFrame = bannerView.frame
    if self.bannerView.bannerLoaded {

        contentFrame.size.height -= sizeForBanner.height
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height
        bannerFrame.size.height = sizeForBanner.height
        bannerFrame.size.width = sizeForBanner.width

        let verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint
        verticalBottomConstraint.constant = sizeForBanner.height
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
        bannerView.hidden = false
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height
        bannerView.hidden = true
        let verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint
        verticalBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    }
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animated ? 0.25 : 0.0, animations: {
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.bannerView.frame = bannerFrame
    })
}
```

Here you call above code to show and hide banner when loads or failed to load iAd

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.layoutAnimated(true)
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.layoutAnimated(true)
}
```

Now you can use `bannerViewActionShouldBegin` and `bannerViewActionDidFinish` to pause and start your app activity. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an Auto Layout issue for `ADBannerView`'s. I implement my `ADBannerView`'s in a similar manner and I've been unable to find a way to silence the warning while at the same time satisfying the flexibility required for my `ADBannerView`. Implementing an AdMob `GADBannerView` in the same exact way does not cause an Auto Layout warning to occur. As you can see in my screen shot, the `ADBannerView` will indeed be stretched across the devices screen, `width = 600`, but Auto Layout still thinks it is at the default size, `width = 480`.

The best answer at this time is to simply ignore the warning.

[image: ADBannerViewAutoLayout]

[**Fullscreen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIUWz.png)